# Is it possible to implement multiple in jquery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a problem with multiple `CheckBoxes`

**Markup**

```
<p>
  <label>Display 1</label>
  <input class="show-options" id="one" name="name" type="checkbox" value="1" />
</p>

<p>
  <label>Display 2</label>
  <input class="show-options" id="second" name="name" type="checkbox" value="2" />
</p>

<div class="show-options-panel" style="display: none;">
  <p>Checkbox 1</p>
</div>

<div class="show-options-panel" style="display: none;">
  <p>Checkbox 2</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $('.show-options').live('change', function(){
      if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.show-options-panel').show('medium');
      } else {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.show-options-panel').hide('medium');
      }
 });

});
```

Is it possible to create a multiple `CheckBoxes` with that markup? Here's the example http://jsfiddle.net/satryabima/CupF3/1/

**UPDATE**

Here's the solution from my friend http://jsfiddle.net/neosheet/9y44X/

Comment: Your first problem is that your checkboxes have the same value for their ID attributes. Make them unique, and get rid of the name attributes and it should work.

Comment: I'm sorry about the ID attributes, it just an example markup :)

Comment: Suggestion to read [this](http://api.jquery.com/live/) about using `.live()`.

Answer (score 1):

You just gave your showpanel the same class so that when one checkbox activated your *.show-options-panel* the other one won't show the same panel again, because it's already visible with the wrong text of course.
And your checkboxes have the same id, that's not cool.

To get a feeling of what is clicked, you should edit your code like this:

**HTML**

```
<p>
  <label>Display 1</label>
  <input class="show-options" id="first" name="name" type="checkbox" value="1" />
</p>

<p>
  <label>Display 2</label>
  <input class="show-options" id="second" name="name" type="checkbox" value="2" />
</p>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('.show-options').on('change', function(){
        if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
            console.log($(this).attr("id") + " checked");
        } 
        else {
            console.log($(this).attr("id") + " unchecked");
        }
    });
});
```

If you than open your Javascript Console Window in your Browser, you see what's going on.
Another option would be to use two show panels with different text and different id and you show and hide them based on the id or some other deterministic attribute of the checkboxes, like value or data-attribute.

Cheers.

Comment: I see `one checked`, `one unchecked`, `second checked `, `second unchecked ` .So, basically my markup is not possible to implement the mulitiple checkboxes?

Comment: What should it display in your opinion? Or what do you want to see?

Comment: I need like http://jsfiddle.net/mambows/CupF3/2/ , but the problem is I can't change the markup :(

Comment: Congrats, but your question was not very precise then.